# How to fix header of Interactive Grid in Oracle apex 5.0

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

Is there any way to fix header of Interactive Grid in Oracle apex 5.0 as Heading--> Fixed to Page doesn't seem to work in apex 5.0.

Answer (score 1):

One solution that I found was to change Heading--> Fixed to Region with max report height as 700 Pixels. This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Not in a simple manner, as far as I can tell & remember (don't use Apex 5 for quite a while now). Anyway: in more recent versions you'd set "Minimum column width" as described below. I *hope* it existed in version 5. Give it a try.

- run the page
- "Actions" button
- "Columns" menu item
- set "Minimum Column Width (Pixel)" value
- Save report

Comment: This will only change the column width of the report. But I want to fix the header on top of thr page of the whole report.

Comment: Aha, something like "Freeze top row" in MS Excel? Sorry, I wouldn't know how to do that.

Comment: As you know, this is done for you in the current version of APEX. You could reverse engineer what was done there, but that sounds like a waste of time. I'd recommend letting the requestor know that this will be done when you upgrade APEX. I know, there are many reasons people push back on upgrades, but you should push back on manually adding features that are now included and done better than is likely possible in previous versions of APEX.

Comment: They don't wanna upgrade anytime soon. Anyways,I got a workaround so thanks.